# Add promise result to items in array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filereader

What i've been trying to do is add the files and their matching dataurl into objects in an array.

Files is a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileList) object.

I first tried this inside the `onloadend` event of the [Filereader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) but couldn't access the original file during reading so moved onto promises.

```
var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
   data.push({
        file: files[i],   //keep the files for uploading
        src: readFile(files[i]) // generate the src to offer preview image
    });
    var last = data.length -1;
    console.log(last); //log a
    data[last].src.then(function(result){
        console.log(last); // log b
        data[last].src = result // overwrite the src deffered object with the result of the promise
    });
}
```

`readFile` is returning a deferred promise, assume this to be working.

this is working fine when files has a length of 1 but when files is multiple im having issues with the asynchronous side of things and it only working for the last item.

Result of logs based on 2 files (files.length == 2):

```
0 //log a
1 //log a
1 //log b <-- ignores 0 stays as 1
1 //log b
```

expecting 0101

Comment: This is an issue with looping and closures which has been answered here before, see, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/623518 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/27254735/623518.

Comment: You really should use `Promise.all` instead of manually assigning or even overwriting things anywhere. Btw, `data[last]` is the object literal with `file` and `src` properties, and does not have a `then` method?

Comment: You are correct I missed out src when extracting an example of code. I'll have a look at .all, im still fairly new to promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

You can solve it by binding the index to the callback:

```
data[last].then(function(index, result){
    data[index].src = result;
}.bind(null, last));
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked but could you tell me where index has come from, and why you're passing null into the bind?

Comment: `.bind` returns a new function and passes the second and further arguments to that function. So `index` is passed the value of `last`. The first argument of `.bind` is the value `this` gets bound to. But since we don't need to bind `this` to a specific value, I just passed `null`. Learn more about `.bind` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind