# reader.onload closure not firing

Tags: javascript, file, filereader

I am doing a simple file text upload using FileReader.

```
var filesInput = document.getElementById("txtImport");

for (var i = 0; i < filesInput.files.length; i++) {
    current = filesInput.files[i];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(file) {
        return function(e) {
            console.log('e', e) // not logging
        }
    }(current)
}
```

Upon reading [FileReader onload with result and parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254735/filereader-onload-with-result-and-parameter), I need to use closure so as to not lose the scope inside the loop. When I click the button to trigger the upload, why is the log not coming up? Why isn't the function firing?

Answer (score 5):

You need to call one of the `readAs___` methods of the `FileReader`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

If you're reading multiple files parallel, you need a separate reader for each.

Also, the parameter the event handler receives is an event object, not the contents of the file. Those will be in `reader.result`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < filesInput.files.length; i++) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        console.log(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsText(filesInput.files[i]);
}
```

Comment: That worked but can you explain why I didn't need to use closure to not lose the scope?

Comment: Functions have access to all variables in the scope where they are defined. Thus, the handler function can see the `FileReader` because they were defined in the same scope. Each iteration of the loop creates a new `FileReader` and a new function, so each function sees a different reader. Does that make sense?

Comment: MDN also has a more detailed explanation here, that'll probably do you more good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link and explanation! Going off of this, I'm trying to assign `reader.result` to a variable inside the onload function - however, logging the variable outside of the onload returns undefined. What's going on there?

Comment: @patrickhuang94 Sorry, just noticed your edit. Did you do something like this: `reader.onload = function(event) { var fileContents = reader.result; }` ? The emphasis here is that the `fileContents` variable is declared inside the `onload` function. Local variables are only visible inside the function where they're declared. You need to store the results in a broader scope if you want other functions to access it.